# RTX 2070 = Bad performance on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I'm new to Ubuntu especially to Linux and I have an RTX 2070 Nvidia card. But I have some problems with it. When running Discord, the whole system running "sluggish" like at 50fps (I have a 165hz screen so I'm feeling it a lot.) but not only that, it also makes random freezes for about 0.5-1seconds of the whole system. So I can't really use Discord (which is a program I need to work properly!).

Not only that but when I use Chromium, at random times it also makes the whole system feel like it's in 50fps for a short amount of time but it happens a lot.

> **Hardware Information:**

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070
Nvidia-Driver Version: 450.57 (Open-Source)
Motherboard: Gigabyte B450M DS3H (BIOS Up-to-date)
Memory: 2x8 Corsair Vengeance 3000Mhz
Display: Dell S3220DGF QHD 165HZ FreeSync2 HDR
The display is connected via DisplayPort v1.4
```

> dkms status

```
nvidia, 450.57, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
```

> sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

> nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   34C    P8    21W / 175W |    671MiB /  7979MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1139      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 53MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1688      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                264MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1891      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              138MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2440      G   ...llation/ubuntu12_32/steam       42MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3574      G   ./steamwebhelper                    2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3613      G   ...token=9331796403822947178       57MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6107      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       97MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Maybe switching from the gnome-desktop environment will fix the issue?? I'm a newbie :/

Comment: Open the `nvidia-settings` and set the `performance` mode for Your GPU.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz
```nvidia-settings``` has returned output: https://pastebin.com/raw/AkPpA9Ua ; Where do I set the performance mode? (sorry for being a noob).